# Find control position relative to the parent form when it is inside a splittercontainer

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, windows-10, rectangles

### SCENARIO

---

I'm developing a user-control that is used to mirror a target window, it internally uses the Win32 DWM API to register/unregister a thumbnail and update the thumbnail position and location whenever the parent Form resizes or moves.

This is the structure of my application:

[image]

The application/my user-control works as expected in "normal" conditions (that means, when using the default Windows theme in the operating system), I recorded the next video that demonstrates the user-control usage and behavior, so you can get a better idea of all this and also see the control works as expected:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fy3MLMpEUTg

### PROBLEM

---

The problem begins when I manage to use a different theme for the operating system, specifically any theme that adds non-invisible borders for windows in Windows 10, this can be reproduced like for example using 3rd party software like [WindowBlinds](https://www.stardock.com/products/windowblinds/) (with a theme named "[Flat Dark](https://www.wincustomize.com/explore/windowblinds/8764/)"), maybe modifying some windows metrics values in the registry could reproduce too the addition of visible borders in Windows 10, but I don't remember how to do that through registry, sorry.

Well, the main thing is that under in Windows 10, when managed to use windows with non-invisible borders (trough the 3rd party software mentioned or by other possible ways), the algorithm that I have inside my user-control class to retrieve its relative coordinates to the parent form, it breaks, and then I get unexpected coordinates so the DWM thumbnail is not drawn on the correct location at which it should be drawn.

I recorded the next video on which you can see the differences and understand the problem:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zujIy88ehp0

in the video firstly I show the program running in "normal" conditions, then I close the program, I change the operating system theme, I run again the program and from this point you can see that the DWM thumbnail is not drawn in the correct coordinates...

All my conjectures suggest me that the problem I'm having is related with the client/non-client area of my Form, when the Form/window has non-invisible Windows 10 borders applied.

Why I think that?, because if I change the theme to have windows with visible borders, and then I remove the borders of my form like this:

```
this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
```

...then my application works fine again while my form its borderless, so it must be an issue related to the client/non-client area of my form in these specific circumstances, and I don't get what I'm doing wrong when I calculate the relative position of my control in these circumstances, when the form has borders.

### SOURCE-CODE

---

Finally, I share here the complete solution, it includes the user-control that I'm developing and also a demo application (the same that you can see in the videos above).

- http://www.mediafire.com/file/gntmrabtbhptzo7/ElektroDwmThumbnail.zip/file

Note that the source-code its written in VB.NET, but that fact has nothing to do with the languages I tagged in this question because I accept any solution in C# or VB.NET, so please do not recriminate this because the tagged languages in the question is one thing, and a shared solution wrote in one specific language is a different thing.

It is not necessary to download and inspect the source-code, the only relevant part of all the source-code is the coordinate assignment of `relativePos`, here:

```
Public Class ElektroDwmThumbnail : Inherits UserControl

    Protected Function GetThumbnailRectangle() As Rectangle
        Dim relativePos As Point = Me.ParentForm.PointToClient(Me.PointToScreen(Point.Empty))
        ' ...
        Dim dstRectangle As New Rectangle(relativePos, thumbnailSize)
        Return dstRectangle
    End Function

End Class
```

Which in C# would be:

```
public class ElektroDwmThumbnail: UserControl {

    protected Rectangle GetThumbnailRectangle() {
        Point relativePos = this.ParentForm.PointToClient(this.PointToScreen(Point.Empty));
        // ...
        Rectangle dstRectangle = new Rectangle(relativePos, thumbnailSize);
        return dstRectangle;
    }

}
```

...it assigns unexpected coordinates to `relativePos` in the circumstance that I explained, that is what I need to solve and what I'm asking for, I need to determine the real relative coordinates of my user-control to the parent form, efficiently (universally), regardless of the border size of the parent form window...

Comment: WindowBlinds is quite notorious for causing problems like this.  Nothing you can about it in your code.  Only two basic workarounds I can think of:  be sure to add a manifest to declare your app to be dpiAware, would fix the problem if dpi virtualization is the cause.  And the thing you had to do in Windows version previous to Win10, if you changed the theme and the non-client area metrics changed then it recommended to log out and log back in.  Try that first.

Comment: @Hans Passant Thanks for comment, but see, I'm not sure how to attribute the problem to WindowBlinds,or to the algorithm,I mean,the coordinate calculation of my program returns exact same coordinates when using a theme or another theme,well,if this were a problem attributable to WindowBlinds then by that rule of three it should not the positions of all controls go crazy in the operating system?(since all the controls will return the same coordinates regardless of the theme in use),logically that does not happen,it only happens when I try to calculate the coordinates of this specific control.

Comment: (Not enough space to answer) Unless I did something wrong, I added the manifest file via Visual Studio "New Item" menu, and then I declared it dpiAware, I also tried with gdiScaling property, I set them aware and unaware, the results were the same. The second workaround about relogging user session is not the cause.

Comment: I would like to remark that this problem happens when using a 3rd party theme, yes, but ONLY if my form has borders, that is, If I make a borderless form then the coordinate calculation works fine, my DWM thumbnail is drawn in the right location. Then... at the moment I try to do the coordinate calculation something could be wrong/missing with border size calculation or something else... I don't know.

Answer (score 5):

Regardless of the control type or the parent of the control or how deep the control is located in controls tree, here is an extension method which helps you to find the control bounds relative to the host form:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public static class ControlExtensions
{
    public static Rectangle GetBoundsRelativeToForm(this Control c)
    {
        if (c == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(c));

        var form = c.FindForm();
        if (form == null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("The control is not located on a form.");

        var parent = c.Parent;
        if (parent == null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("The control does not have a parent.");

        var p = form.PointToClient(parent.PointToScreen(c.Location));
        return new Rectangle(p, c.Size);
    }
}
```

for example:

```
var r = textBox1.GetBoundsRelativeToForm();
```

---

I reproduced the problem and I see the location is calculated correctly. But `DwmRegisterThumbnail` is assuming the whole window area as client area, while it's expected to use the client area.

I believe it's the problem of theme and as a quick fix, I corrected the location this way:

```
Dim p0 As Point = Me.ParentForm.PointToScreen(Point.Empty)
Dim p1 As Point = Me.ParentForm.DesktopLocation
Dim relativePos As Point = Me.ParentForm.PointToClient(Me.PointToScreen(Point.Empty)) 
relativePos.X += (p0.X - p1.X)
relativePos.Y += (p0.Y - p1.Y)
```

In fact using this code, I'm adding the border width and title-bar height to the result.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177890/discussion-on-answer-by-reza-aghaei-find-control-position-relative-to-the-parent).

Comment: Since the problem is not there for standard themes, most likely it's a problem for 3rd party themes. Currently I don't have any idea about how can you detect if the theme has such problem, so just sharing the fix for that specific theme mentioned in the question. Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Below sample code will help you to find Control position relative to form. Form can be border-less or with border.

**Use below method as extension for Control type. Or just remove this keyword from parameter to make it as normal method**

```
public static Point GetPositionInForm(this Control ctrl)
{
    Point p = ctrl.Location;
    Control parent = ctrl.Parent;
    Form frm = ctrl.FindForm();
    Rectangle screenRectangle = frm.RectangleToScreen(frm.ClientRectangle);
    int titleHeight = screenRectangle.Top - frm.Top;
    int leftMargin = screenRectangle.Left - frm.Left;
    p.Offset(leftMargin, titleHeight);

    while (!(parent is Form))
    {
        p.Offset(parent.Location.X, parent.Location.Y);
        parent = parent.Parent;
    }
    return p;
}
```